# Cannot get Jquery to work with wordpress

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out why Jquery isn't working on my Wordpress site. Am I setting it up right?  Any help or suggestions is appreciated! Thanks.

Here is what I have in my function.php

```
 function my_scripts_method() {
     wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
     wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    
     add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

and on my header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
            <title> 
    <?php
        wp_title('-', true, 'right');
        bloginfo( 'name');
    ?>
    </title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
      <!--[if lt IE 9]!>
 <script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: What happens when you use the correct jQuery version? I mean the one shipped with WordPress. It is not compatible with Google’s.

Comment: Are you referring to:

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

It still wasn't working when I plugged this into function.php

Comment: What do you need in 1.10 that isn't in 1.8.3 (the version that comes with WordPress)?

Comment: @AndrewBartel I ended up plugging this in and it worked. http://pastebin.com/7WK6pcAf . I still don't understand why wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); in functions.php didn't work.

Comment: Did just enqueueing your new js file not work..?  You're treading into dangerous territory as far as code maintainability and future upgrades here.

Comment: @AndrewBartel it turned out that my jquery was loading up good. It was the myscript.js that wouldn't load. I plugged in myscript.js in the footer and the console would give me a 404. I'm definitely in the danger zone as of now lol.

Comment: So nuke everything involving deregistering, etc with jquery and just wrap a wp_enqueue_script(your_script) in a function hooked to add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','your_function') and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have to register jquery. I just put this in my functions.php:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'main',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

It includes my custom scripts that are reliant on jquery.

Comment: I tried that too.Here is the link http://listentotheway.com/pics/ . That text should be blinking but if you look in dev tool, it's not finding myscript.js .

Comment: Your jquery is loading fine. Did you check the path to your script? Right now it is ` <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>` It should have your root directory at the beginning of the src.

Comment: Yeah, it showing that it loads in in http://listentotheway.com/js/myscript.js. However, in the console, I'm getting a 404 in there. I just tried     <script type="text/javascript"
      src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/myscript.js"></script> and getting an error. I guess I'm in a jquery problem now and am in the wrong forum unless you have suggestions, I'll take them lol.

Comment: I think it should be `src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You should also enqueue you other JavaScript files and be sure that your jQuery dependent scripts are loaded after jQuery is loaded.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); // Will load jquery from WordPress built in jquery handle

wp_register_script(
    'theme-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
    array('jquery'), // dependencies
    '1', // your version number
    true // script in footer
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-script' );*/
```

Comment: I plugged in your code as well as @vinod Dalvi in functions.php and got it working. I don't know if that's the correct way to do things but it works for now. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Check the jquery url in your code it is without http:// protocol which is wrong, it should be with http://  so the correct code is as following :

```
function my_scripts_method() {
 wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
 wp_register_script( 'jquery','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I changed it and it's still not working for some reason. I'll have to keep going at it until I figure it out. Appreciate it.

Comment: here is the link to my problem. The text should be blinking but isn't finding my myscript.js. Any help is appreciated! Thanks http://listentotheway.com/pics/

Answer (score 0):

Delete what you have in your functions.php. Install the Use Google Libraries plugin. Once activated, you will see that there are no settings or such. There is nothing to do. Just activate the plugin. 
The Javascript should work now. Quick tip: put it in the footer (before the `</body>` tag) for faster site loading.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just did that, thanks. I'm looking in the console and it's not finding script.js. Here is what I have at the footer. I'm plugging it in correctly, yes?

      <?php wp_footer(); ?>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Delete the code: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Install the "Use Google Libraries" plugin instead. It should work. Also, just double checking, the script.js file has working javascript and is in the correct path?